# Flutter SQLite database table exists but not detected by SQFLite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I wanted to fill a SQLite database with some initial data required for my app so I made a flutter app and used it to fill generate that database with the SQFLite package and then took it and put it in the assets folder of the app it will be used in, but when I query the initial data table it tells me that the table doesn't exist although the file size says that there is data in there and I used an online SQLite viewer website and the table with the data were there, So what to do?!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to dump an existing database is schema is:

```dart
print(await db.query("sqlite_master"));
```

Without code, hard to say whether you correctly [open the database from your assets](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md).

You should also check that the existing database has indeed the data using some 3rd party tool (sqlite3, sqlite browser).

Comment: Of course, I have tried to check the schema, simply the table wasn't there and If I created it using a raw query then it gives me a new empty table. Anyway, so I can't open the database file directly from the assets folder and I have to copy it somewhere in the system first, so if the database file size was 10MBs then when I copy the file to the system the app size increases by 10MBs right?!

Comment: Indeed you have to copy it, on Android, an asset is not a file AFAIK. And yes it will take an additional 10MB on the storage (the app size itself does not change).